# Stored procedure error handling : no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that connects to three server :

```
Begin  
Select dept from Server1.DB1.dbo.orders  
union  
Select dept from Server2.DB1.dbo.orders  
union  
Select dept from Server3.DB1.dbo.orders  
End
```

Problem is when you cannot connect to one of the servers:

> msg 10061, level 16, state 1
>   tcp provider:no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Will be great if when you cannot connect to a server the field data is replaced by 'ServerFailedToConnect' - we get select data from the servers we can connect to rather than the whole thing falling over.

What would be the best way to error handle this...

Comment: 1:  Figure out which of the 3 servers is not working.  Try each one at a time.     2:   Look at the settings for that Linked server,  ( CurrentServer \ Server Objects \ Linked Servers )   look at user connections or machine name vs ip address or port settings.   3: consider if your "bad" address is actually going to the server you think it is.    4: try to go to the "bad" server directly to make sure you know a worklng set of addresses and sign on's.

Comment: TCP/IP error 10061 is usually returned by firewall blocking connection - ask your sysadmin to configure servers properly. About your question - instead of union perform three selects into temp table, this way you can separate select statements and handle their errors seprately.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TRY…CATCH Block`
For Ex:

```
BEGIN TRY
--your query
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT  ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```